# Which Maven dependencies are needed for Cucumber, am using Testng as my test-framework

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber, testng, browser-automation

Here are the tools/jars in my automation framework

1. Selenium
2. Testng
3. Maven
4. Jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is redundant here. The minimum dependencies for you are:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thx, and can you explain "cucumber-jvm-deps" is for

Comment: There are some JARs that Cucumber depends on that are not part of a specific Cucumber release. Gherkin is the name of the dialect that Cucumber uses to specify feature files. the relevant gherkin jar is automatically a part of your dependency. Cucumber makes use of some other tools as well that have a lot to do with the internal plumbing of how the feature file constructs connect up with step definitions. These, and others, are packaged in the cucumber-jvm-deps jar.

Comment: you need to add </dependencies> at the end

Answer (score 0):

Above dependencies are outdated. Use latest version instead (note the group id changed):

For cucumber:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(Note: you can also use cucumber-java8 if you want to use lambda syntax)

For cucumber-testng:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: make sure to use the same cucumber version

Afaik you don't need the `cucumber-jvm-deps` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Below listed Dependencies are enough to start with cucumber,

Add this cucumber dependencies to pom.xml in your maven project:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Also while writing TestRunner class just hover on @RunWith annotation and add testng libraries from suggestion.

Do not forget to add selenium and testng dependencies,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I hope this information will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the dependencies you need:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```